# Fancybox in Bootstrap not triggering slides

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, fancybox

I recently made an image gallery page on my website using Bootstrap 3 and Fancybox 3. My active page is located here. http://rye03870.com/photos.html The gallery looks how I want it to but when you click an image, the Fancybox doesn't work.

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>Photos</h1>
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/1.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/1.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/2.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/2.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/3.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/3.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/4.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/4.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/5.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/5.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/6.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/6.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/7.jpg">
                        <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/7.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/8.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/8.jpg" /> </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/9.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/9.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/10.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/10.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/11.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/11.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/12.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/12.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/13.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/13.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/14.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/14.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/15.jpg">
                        <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/15.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/16.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/16.jpg" /> </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/17.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/17.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/18.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/18.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/19.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/19.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/20.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/20.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/21.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/21.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/22.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/22.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/23.jpg">
                        <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/23.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/24.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/24.jpg" /> </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/25.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/25.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/26.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/26.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/27.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/27.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/28.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/28.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/29.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/29.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/30.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/30.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/31.jpg">
                        <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/31.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/32.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/32.jpg" /> </div>
                  </a>
                </div><div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/33.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/33.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/34.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/34.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/35.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/35.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/36.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/36.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/37.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/37.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/38.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/38.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/39.jpg">
                        <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/39.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/40.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/40.jpg" /> </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/41.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/41.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/42.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/42.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/43.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/43.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/44.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/44.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/45.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/45.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/46.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/46.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/47.jpg">
                        <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/47.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/48.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/48.jpg" /> </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/49.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/49.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/50.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/50.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/51.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/51.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/52.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/52.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/53.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/53.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/54.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/54.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/55.jpg">
                        <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/55.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/56.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/56.jpg" /> </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/57.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/57.jpg" /> </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="images/58.jpg">
                         <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/58.jpg" /> </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
</div></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

This is solved, I had the wrong link for the css.